Issues with FFmpeg in converting linear light bayer image
I'm having trouble using ffmpeg to convert a raw video stream embedded in a SER container to individual images using:
ffmpeg -i my.ser frames_%03d.fits
The data in the stream is encoded as bayerrggb16be pixel format but for whatever reason when I export single frames to tiff or fits, it appears that ffmpeg is not interpreting the 16 bit big endian correctly and the resulting picture is just garbage data:
My workaround to this was to force a grey scale interpretation of pixel format ():
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt gray16be my.ser -pix_fmt + frames_%03d.tif
OR
ffmpeg -r 1 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt gray16be my.ser -f segment -segment_time 1 frames_%03d.fits
(note: exporting to fits requires segmenting the input stream into individual frames otherwise all frames are stored as single fits sequence file)
This works perfectly when I export a fits frame but the underlying raw values seem to shift significantly when I chose tiff as the output format. It seems that there is some color space transformation happening for tiff that's not taking place for the fits container. Even putting -pix_fmt + before the tiff output file name seems to apply some sort of a conversion despite telling ffmpeg to use the same pixel format.
Is there any way to disable color space transformations completely? The colours in these CFA images is recoverable with some curves transformation but because the images contain scientific image data, doing this transformation manually defies the point.

Please edit your post, and add the FFmpeg commands you are using. Are you just asking about forcing grey scale, or are you also asking about bayer rggb16be? In case you are asking about Bayer, please consider sharing a sample input (using Google Drive for example).

I'm asking if disabling color space transformations is possible when exporting to tiff because the encoder seems applying some transformation and modifying my raw pixel data

What is the + inffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt gray16be my.ser -pix_fmt + frames_%03d.tif? Shouldn't you also add -video_size argument?

Try something like ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -pixel_format gray16be -video_size 1920x1080 -i input.ser -pix_fmt gray16le frames_%03d.tif. Modify 1920x1080 to the actual resolution of the raw input video.

Thanks @Rotem, sorry I forgot about the the "-s" to specify the size for rawvideo. the "+" after -pix_fmt according to the documentation is similar to -codec copy, just keeps the same pixel format as the source stream. I'm fairly certain that I tried various output pixel formats such as the gray16le you suggested but there is a fundamental color space transformation taking place to get from one pixel format to another which is causing the issue.

Anyway, I'll try the specific suggestion your provided above to see if it makes a difference. If that doesn't work I'll try to upload a sample ....the trouble with these sequences is that they are huge (10GB+) and the whole point of using ffmpeg is to transform them to more manageable formats including ones based on individual frames.
